# Pandas BigQuery upload stuck in buffer

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I would like to upload a Pandas dataframe to Google BigQuery using the `to_gbq` function:

```
import pandas as pd
dfData = pd.DataFrame(llData, columns=lsHeadings)

sProjectID = dBQConfig['sProjectID']
sTargetDataset = dBQConfig['sTargetDataset']
sTargetTable = dBQConfig['sTargetTable']
sTablePath = "{}.{}".format(sTargetDataset, sTargetTable)

dfData.to_gbq(sTablePath, sProjectID, if_exists='replace')
```

The python script runs successfully, like this (run inside a PySpark job):

```
Streaming Insert is 100% Complete

16/05/19 16:55:38 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
Process finished with exit code 0
```

They table then shows up in BigQuery, *however*, it looks like this:

[image]

And its been like this for almost 24 hours.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it still look like this? That streaming buffer should be flushed into the table regularly.

Comment: It does, but I can do Select * and that seems to work after a while.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I just checked again, and it seems to finally be out of the buffer.  Its strange that I can access the data via a query before it says that it is in the table.  But just waiting for long enough seems to do it.